# Using wire mesh on yard gate for exclusion

Tags: gates, gate-post

I want to put some quarter-inch wire mesh on the hinge side of a yard gate to exclude rabbits from entering the yard. The solution that I'm looking for is something that would exclude rabbits. So far I've only considered the quarter-inch wire mesh that you get from hardware store in rolls. If there's another solution for rabbit exclusion I'm interested in that as well.

I've prototyped where the mesh would go by opening the gate as wide as it will go that it would stretch the mesh to its full extend and then taped some paper on the gate. I then moved the gate to the full extent in the other direction to see how the mesh would buckle when it was compressed. You can see these in the images.

From the paper prototype it looks like the wire mesh might be a problem in restricting the opening and closing of the gate. What are the solutions to this? Other materials that would work? Other methods of creating an exclusion at that point?

Update: Added an image showing the gap as 1 3/8" wide. Rabbits get through that easily.

[image: gate closed]

[image: mesh prototype compressed]

[image: gate open]

[image: mesh prototype stretched]

[image: fence gap]

Comment: Do you actually need to connect the wire to the gate side?  I'd think you could just attach it to the hinge side, because there's not much point in trying to block that gap while the gate is open, because then the rabbits could just... go through the open gate.

Comment: Does this gate swing one way only, or both ways?  And if it swings both ways now, would you be opposed to converting it such that it can only swing one way?

Comment: It's hard to tell with the paper there, but is this gap _really_ big enough for rabbits to get through? Are you keeping the rabbits _in_ or _out_? If you're about to release the pet into the yard and don't want him to escape then worrying about a theoretical problem makes sense. If you're keeping the wild ones out, is this actually a problem?

Comment: are you certain that rabbits are getting into the yard through the hinge gap? ... please post a picture of the gap when the gate is closed without the paper ... inlude the hinge in the picture ... the answer may be multiple hinges

Comment: Hardware cloth (the proper term for that 1/4” mesh) isn’t going to hold up in that application.  You’re bending it too far, too often.

Comment: Drilling into the structural metal of the gate would create points for corrosion.

Comment: I'm thinking of a filler block that is held magnetically to the square tube which is attached to the wall ... use a couple of these to attach some kind of a grid ... it does not have to attach to the moving part of the gate  https://www.ebay.co.uk/p/3012057855?iid=221844998406

Comment: @NateS. The gate swings both ways and I need to keep it like that to allow full access. But I like where you're going with that.

Comment: @FreeMan - Yes - definitely big enough for rabbits. I updated the question with a ruler on the gap. I'm trying to keep them out.

Comment: @JimStewart - agreed. I was planning on a spray paint afterwards to trying and reduce that impact. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: It’ll be difficult to equal the corrosion protection of the LPU or powdercoat it came with from the factory.  Random rattle-can spray paint is better than nothing but not equivalent.

Comment: I've thought of another idea. Is there some sort of 3D printed "chain sheet" that I could attach that would "pull" open with the gate and allow for compression? The PLA that I use for 3D printing is as hard as nails. Sure a rabbit with a lot of time on its paws could eventually chew through that but it would probably take years and then I could print another and replace it. Anybody ever seen something like that done?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - agreed. I'll have to choose between the lesser of the two "evils." :)

Comment: Wow... rabbits are squeezing through a 1 3/8" gap? I don't think those are big enough for eating, @SolarMike. It looks like there's some room _under_ the gate, have you considered that they may squeeze through there? Consider installing a dog in the backyard, he'll keep the squirrels out, too. I would think hardware cloth or heavy window screen, installed on the inside of the gate,  _should_ be flexible enough to make the bends. You may need a strip of spring steel to make it bow out so it doesn't get trapped and crimped when the gate opens inward.

Comment: @FreeMan OP had not done the measuring when I made the comment and also note that the gap **underneath** looks more than 1 3/8" , that was the side gap that was measured.

Comment: Yeah, I know - he mass responded (not that there's a problem with that). Eatin' sounds like a good idea, though!

Comment: Are you 100% certain the gate is their only method of ingress? Is there a tall solid wall surrounding the rest of the property or is there a fence with gaps (as we can see in the background of a pic looking through the gate) or shrubs/trees defining the backyard? If the wall is solid on your side, is there any sort of berm or hill on the other side that they can climb to get to the top of the wall and hop over?

Comment: You could install a vertical rod in line with that hinge. Turn the 1 3/8" gap into two tiny gaps that don't interfere with the motion of the hinge, and avoid the need to damage the painted metal. Alternatively you could install a metal L bracket, again directly under the hinge pin where it won't interfere with the door motion.

Comment: I also didn't believe what tiny gaps rabbits could get through until I saw it. Do a video search and you will be surprised. Here's one https://youtu.be/aEFcey4Y5TA?t=177

Answer (score 3):

Instead of hardware cloth that has to buckle and flex to cover the gap, consider a thin stiff material that could be fixed to narrow the gap. I don't know what size of rabbit skulls you're up against but I have to imagine that if you can narrow the gap to under an inch from the 1-3/8 it is now (ie, block off 1/4 inch from each side) then the heads, and the rest of the bodies, won't be able to pass through.

A bit of material installed to the stile and the jamb (can I use those words in the context of a gate?), in line with the hinges, will narrow the gap while the gate is closed but won't bind or prevent the gate opening either direction. Here are some materials you might find in a home center:

- 1/4 inch square stock (steel or aluminum)
- L profile "angle iron" with legs around 1/2 inch
- sheet metal folded to an L shape (cut down pieces of rectangle HVAC duct)
- flashing/trim/etc from the roofing department

Fasten with screws, magnets, adhesive, foam mounting tape, or whatever suits you and the chosen materials.

Comment: Some good ideas. Thanks. Let me go back to the drawing board with this.